# Can't Download large files in html request

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, filestream, session-timeout

My problem is, I can't download files that are larger than 100mb and I suspect the html request

This is the setHeader from my response

```
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) requestContext.getExternalContext().getNativeResponse();
            response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");        
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+fileName+"\"");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
            response.setHeader("Cache-control", "private");
```

And this is the stream declaration for read the file

```
ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();   
                sos.flush();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String str = br.readLine();
                while (str != null) {                                           
                    sos.write(str.getBytes());
                    sos.write(13);
                    sos.write(10);
                    str = br.readLine();
                }
```

This 'while' works fine for small files but in case of large files, it seems as if the session was lost because I miss debug and does not stop at the next breakpoint.
Is there any way to prevent the execution miss

Comment: Do you get an exception?  If so, please post the stack trace.

Comment: I can't post exception because no exception occurs in the server. The connexion is lost within the 'while'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time flush the output stream object in the while loop after reading some data. you can set a long value and check. if that limit reaches you can flush the data in the output stream object, so that system will flushes that much amount of data and free the memory allocated for that so will not come the out of memory error.

```
ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();
   long byteRead = 0;
   try {
       byte[] buf = new byte[8291];
       while (true) {
         int r = is.read(buf);
         if (r == -1)
         break;
         sos.write(buf, 0, r);
         byteRead +=r;
         if(byteRead > 1024*1024){ //flushes after 1mb
           byteRead = 0;
           sos.flush();
         }

      }
    } finally {
    if(sos != null){
      sos.flush();
    }
    try{is.close();}catch(Exception e){}
    try{sos.close();}catch(Exception e){}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue is that the byte data for an image won't have a newline and you are running out of memory trying to read a line. You need to create a buffer of a fixed size and copy the bytes directly. Something like this:

```
ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();
sos.flush();
try {
    byte[] buf = new byte[1000];
    while (true) {
        int r = is.read(buf);
        if (r == -1)
            break;
        sos.write(buf, 0, r);
    }
} finally {
    try{is.close();}catch(Exception e){}
    try{sos.close();}catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Comment: I find this log in my websphere

1TISIGINFO     Dump Event "systhrow" (00040000) Detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError" received 

Need more memory. THX all

Comment: Yes, but if you use the code above you won't need more memory because you won't be loading the image into memory; you will be reading it out to the client in chunks of 1kb.

Comment: We need to flush the data from ServletOutputStream after reading a particular byte. May be the code will work with small files but chances of getting error with big files is there. Kindly add a 'sos.flush();' after reading every 10kB of data. Try with 2GB file. You can see the code will fail with out implementing the flush() method. Again try the same with flush() implemented .